# saving multiple figures in python to create array plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So say I have several 2 d plots of the usual x-y format:

ex: 1) x=(0,1,2,3,4,..100), y=(0,2,4,6,8,10,....)

I would like to have my x-y scatter plots saved somehow, so that once all the x-y plots are generated, I could merge them on to one big graph where these graphs now form an array. Just imagine if each of the plots represent some kind of a time evolution. I have already tried using savefigure but cannot see a saved file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't find the figures after issuing `plt.savefig(some_filename)`? Find out what is your current working directory, the figure files should be there:

```
import os
os.getcwd() #Gives you the current working directory.
```

Of course, if you not only provided the `filename` but also the `path` to it for `plt.savefig()`, you should see your figure in the `path` you specified.

You figure comes out OK right? If you issue a `plt.show()`, do you get the correct figure?

Comment: No it doesn't work. I have checked the directory, it's correct. but there is no file being saved even though I get no errors. Is there an alternative?